# What are analytic methods used define a parametric equation for an arbitrary curve or surface in 3D?

Tags: geometry, geodesic, parametrization

Given some arbitrary curve or surface in 3D, if I wanted to obtain parameterize function. What are modern (and by hand) analytic methods do so?.

Comment: Usually you solve the equations you're given for some of the variables, as many as the codimension of the given surface or curve. There isn't a general method to do so, you actually need a representation of the curve or surface as an equation or formula.

Comment: @McFry how do you get a formula for an arbitrary surface in that case?

Comment: You can't magically get exact formulas from nowhere, if you want a formula you need to have a formula first. You can construct approximations though, like interpolation surfaces or splines.

Comment: @McFry what does "if you want a formula you need a formula " mean here. So methods to obtain parametrized representation (approx) of curve/surface involve "splicing and interpolation". Do you have ref to any introductory  materials of these methods that are particular good?

Answer (score 1):

If you know your curve or surface by having samples (i.e., many points on the surface), then various kinds of splines give good approximate fittings to data. If you know it as an implicit surface, then the implicit function theorem gives ways to parametrize it, although it may involve root-finding, which is computationally intractable.

Finally, there are a great many papers from the last 10 years or so in Computer Graphics on the subject of "parameterization" in which surfaces represented by polygonal meshes are given parametric descriptions, although usually the parametric description is of some smooth-ish surface that's well approximated by the input poly-mesh. See recent proceedings of the SIGGRAPH conference, for instance, as a starting point for many papers on this topic.